# JQuery stop show/hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, show, show-hide

I have a code snippet that shows a div once you click the menu item, there are different divs on this space and what the menu does is hide the one that was there before and show the new one, the problem is when I click on the same menu item it shows the current div again and I want to stop that from happening, it should only show the animation if it's not the current one, if it is nothing should happen.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
     if (curPage.length) { 
        $("#"+curPage).hide("slide");
     }
     curPage=$(this).data("page");
     $("#"+curPage).show("slide");
});
```

And here is a demo of how it's occuring now: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfsvc1ta/

Comment: do you want in this way https://jsfiddle.net/Lfsvc1ta/1/?

Comment: That's still showing the animation once I click the same link, I know I sound confusing, thank you for taking the time to answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an additional check to see whether `curPage` is the same as the clicked page.

```
var curPage;
$("#menu a").click(function () {
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    if (curPage && page != curPage) {
        $("#" + curPage).stop().hide("slide");
    }
    $("#" + page).stop().show("slide");

    curPage = page;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/78eu5xuq/)

Comment: Thank you, the other answers are also right but I'm voting this one up as it also showed me the .stop() function to cut the animation once I click on another link, that's really cool and I did not know it, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Check what data-page is clicked first bro.

```
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var newPage = $(this).data("page");
    if (newPage !== curPage) {
         $("#"+curPage).hide("slide");
         $("#"+newPage).show("slide");
         curPage = newPage;
    }         
});
```

Comment: What you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what the before page was, adding a variable.

```
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
     var page=$(this).data("page");
     if (curPage!=page && curPage.length) { 
        $("#"+curPage).hide("slide");
         curPage=$(this).data("page");
     }
     $("#"+curPage).show("slide");
});
```

Like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7b1wh70h/

Comment: This answer is also correct, thank you, it gives me insight on how to handle situations like this, I completely forgot that, I'm pretty new to programming, thank you for taking the time to answer!